# How can I use YUI Node with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, yui

I'm using Portal Software that uses the YUI Library as its native JS Framework and I want to use jQuery on the various YUI Nodes.

Can someone please show me how this is done? I've tried the following with no success...

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    var oneElementById     = Y.one('#foo');
    $(oneElementById).css('color','red');

});
```

​

Comment: `YUI` seletors return `YUI object` and `jQuery` selectors return `jQuery object` and you cannot use `jQuery methods` for `YUI objects`.

Comment: Ok, but is there YUI function that returns a HTML Object, that I can then store and call jQuery on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're doing in your example, you could do something like:

```
var nativeDomElementById = Y.one('#foo').getDOMNode();
$(nativeDomElementById).css('color','red');
```

In general, for fluency between YUI and jQuery, see the http://jsrosettastone.com site that Kevin mentioned. You have to be careful when "crossing the streams" between YUI and jQuery, as they use different abstractions around nodes & events.

If you're working with jQuery and YUI together in a YUI sandbox -- say, you want to load a jQuery plugin alongside YUI, this recipe from the YUI 3 Cookbook might be helpful: https://github.com/evangoer/yui3-cookbook/blob/master/examples/loading/use_jquery.html

And if you get stuck, drop into #yui IRC channel on freenode.net. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that?
to do what you want you just use setStyle instead of css, the api is very similar [JS Rosetta stone jquery and yui api comparison](http://www.jsrosettastone.com/#css)

Comment: that was just an example I'm not actually applying CSS, Im applying a jQuery plugin. I wouldnt be using YUI at all, if it wasnt for the fact the Portal uses YUI  for its events such as the one im using which gets fired each time a portlet is finished rendering

Comment: What plugin are you using that's not available for YUI?